# Конфликт между менеджерами компоновки

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout

Создаю приложение на *Python* с использованием *PyQt5*.

Форма скомпонована следующим образом:

```
class Window(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags()
                        | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
                        | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint
                        | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
    self.setWindowTitle('NetScan')
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons\\icon.ico'))
    self.__input_label = QLabel('Host')
    self.__text = QLineEdit()
    self.__port_one_label = QLabel('Port 1')
    self.__port_one_text = QLineEdit()
    self.__port_two_label = QLabel('Port 2')
    self.__port_two_text = QLineEdit()
    self.__but_submit = QPushButton('Scan')
    self.__but_submit.setIcon(QIcon('icons\\scan.png'))
    self.__but_submit.clicked.connect(self.__click_port_scan)
    self.__box_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.__h_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__input_label)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__text)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_one_label)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_one_text)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_two_label)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_two_text)
    self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__but_submit)
    self.__list_view = QListWidget()
    self.__f_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    self.__f_layout.addWidget(self.__list_view)
    self.__box_layout.addLayout(self.__h_layout)
    self.__box_layout.addLayout(self.__f_layout)
    self.__bar = QStatusBar(self)
    self.__box_layout.addWidget(self.__bar)
    self.setLayout(self.__box_layout)
```

На первый взгляд здесь все отлично, но при запуске в консоли выводиться сообщение:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to Window "", 
> which already has a layout

Насколько я понял, это конфликт между виджетами?
Подскажите, как можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

class Window(QDialog):  # (QWidget): #

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags()
                            | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint
                            | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint
                            | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('NetScan')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icons\\icon.ico'))

        self.__input_label = QLabel('Host')
        self.__text = QLineEdit()
        self.__port_one_label = QLabel('Port 1')
        self.__port_one_text = QLineEdit()
        self.__port_two_label = QLabel('Port 2')
        self.__port_two_text = QLineEdit()
        self.__but_submit = QPushButton('Scan')
        self.__but_submit.setIcon(QIcon('icons\\scan.png'))
        self.__but_submit.clicked.connect(self.__click_port_scan)

        self.__box_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)                       
        self.__h_layout = QHBoxLayout()                            # - self   <---
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__input_label)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__text)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_one_label)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_one_text)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_two_label)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__port_two_text)
        self.__h_layout.addWidget(self.__but_submit)
        self.__list_view = QListWidget()
        self.__f_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__f_layout.addWidget(self.__list_view)
        self.__box_layout.addLayout(self.__h_layout)
        self.__box_layout.addLayout(self.__f_layout)
        self.__bar = QStatusBar(self)
        self.__box_layout.addWidget(self.__bar)
#        self.setLayout(self.__box_layout)                          # -

    def __click_port_scan(self):
        print("def __click_port_scan(self):")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Window()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]